# How to safely convert `ToBase64String` in chunks?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

This is my current code:

```
    public void WriteXml(System.Xml.XmlWriter writer)
    {
        CloseConnection();
        using (Stream source = File.Open(DataBaseFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[source.Length];
            source.Read(buffer, 0, (int)source.Length);
            writer.WriteString(Convert.ToBase64String(buffer));
        }
        OpenConnection();
    }
```

What this does is embed a database into an XML file (this method belongs to the class of a field in another class that is the one being serialized). The problem is that whenever the database is about 300MB I get an OutOfMemory exception on the `byte[] buffer = new byte[source.Length];` line. So I guees I need to do it on chunks. But I'm not sure how would that be. I think these chunks would need to be of a particular size. Also, I think `Convert.ToBase64String` will add two "==" symbols at the end of the string so I will probably have to erase them each time until the last one.

Comment: Why are you converting a 300 MB file into an XML file?

Comment: And because I want to embed it in the "Project" file where lots of other things are saved. I should probably use binary serialization but there are other things I have to fix first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a Base64 stream class: [link text](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=streams&file=Base64Stream.cs)

Answer (score 3):

Base64 encodes each sequence of 6 bits into one character. (Hence the name: 2^6 = 64 possible characters.)

4 such characters therefore align to exactly 3 bytes (24 bits).

In other words, the size of your chunks must be a multiple of 3: 3 bytes, or 6 bytes, or 300 bytes...

Answer (score 1):

[base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding) will always pad to multiple of 4 chars. I think as long as you chop in N*4 sized chunks you are fine.

Comment: Wrong way around, you would want to split it on 3 byte boundaries as ToBase64String goes from 3 bytes to 4 :)

Comment: 3 chars before encoding or 4 after.

Answer (score -1):

Why not do:

```
writer.WriteString(Convert.ToBase64String(File.ReadAllBytes(DataBaseFileName)));
```

Comment: this is going to have the same issue. File.ReadAllBytes() will return a byte[] which is not any different than is in the question.